# Getting values of Objects from Monos in a list after blocking for all of them

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, reactor, reactive-streams

I am following Rossen Stoyanchev's demo on Spring Reactive

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IZ2SoXUiS7M&t=935s

, and calling three delayed API's and then blocking until they are all done.

```
List<Mono<Person>> personMonos = Stream.of(1, 2, 3)
        .map(i -> client.get().uri("/person/{id}", i).retrieve().bodyToMono(Person.class))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

// Declare that we want to block until all monos in the list are done
Mono.when(personMonos).block();
```

Next, can I get the values of the three returned Person object's after blocking completed for the three calls? If so, how?

Answer (score 3):

You can zip all your Monos to do some action when all of them are done like:

```java
Mono.zip(Mono.just(1), Mono.just(2), Mono.just(3)).block();
```

Comment: I think this is the correct answer. At least, this is the answer I was looking for :-)

Answer (score 2):

A list of mono is a flux and a flux can be used like this:

```
@Test
public void test() {

    Flux<Person> persons = Flux.just(1, 2, 3)
            .map(this::doRequest);

    List<Person> personList = persons.collectList().block();
}


@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Getter
static class Person {
    private final int id;
}

private Person doRequest(int id) {
    return new Person(id);
}
```

You can find more information here: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/snapshot/reference/#core-features